# Using local variables in another script

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to run another Python script from my file. It is a PyGame game and after certain coordinates I want it to start another script.

Works fine but I also want my character's coordinates to be transferred but since I have self.x and self.y as local variables, I can't figure out a way to transfer them.

I tried writing from file1 import * into file2, but then it just resets it's coordinates, but doesn't change the background.

I can't use return to get local variables, because then it ends the function's work before importing file2

Any other ways to access there coordinates in the other file?

Might also mention that all of these functions are inside a class.

```
class myclass():
    def __init__(self):
    """ The constructor of the class """
    self.image = picture
    self.x = 300
    self.y = 300

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 0.5
    if key[PYGAME.K_UP]:
     #bunch of functions with coordinates
         if self.y<10: #i indented this
              import file2  #and this
```

I want to use self.y and self.x in file2.

At the moment I get, that this is not defined in the other file.

Comment: Do you have a minimal example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to pass complete control to `file2`'s code? What would be the benefit of that over keeping all the code in `file1`?

Comment: Well I don't really know. I want the game to change background when it reaches the edge of a picture. But the coordinates in which a pop-up needs to occur are different in every picture. I thought multiple scripts might be a good solution, but suggestions are welcome.